# Identifying seasonality in a quarterly time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am attempting to understand whether there is seasonality in the quarterly time series below.

[image]

```
y <-ts(Macro[1:13,2], start = c(2016, 1), frequency = 4) 
y

     Qtr1    Qtr2    Qtr3    Qtr4
2016 148.788 171.274 138.025 503.331
2017 155.381 176.617 144.074 521.484
2018 160.645 179.090 135.418 521.809
2019 152.100      

fit <- ets(y)
ets(y)
plot(forecast(fit))
```

By fitting the below time series using ETS (part of the forecasting package), I get the following output:

```
ETS(M,N,A) 

Call:
ets(y = y) 

 Smoothing parameters:
alpha = 0.0002 
gamma = 0.0003 

 Initial states:
l = 245.5385 
s=267.8483 -106.6074 -69.7656 -91.4754

 sigma:  0.0236

  AIC      AICc       BIC 
88.27329 110.67329  92.22794
```

Clearly the output indicates seasonality is present.  But how do I interpret this output?  Specifically, how do the values

```
  s=267.8483 -106.6074 -69.7656 -91.4754
```

tell me which quarters have seasonality (and thus need to be accounted for in any model)?

Answer (score 1):

The values

> s=267.8483 -106.6074 -69.7656 -91.4754

Are the initial values of the seasonal components that were used to estimate your model.  [Choice of initial values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Choosing_the_initial_smoothed_value) in exponential smoothing and state space models (which is what ETS uses) is tricky, and can have an influence on the quality of the forecast. I assume that ETS() is returning the estimates of the initial states for informational purposes.

> tell me which quarters have seasonality (and thus need to be accounted for in any model)?

Seasonality is a concept that applies to a time series as a whole, not a specific period of the series. So you can't have some quarters that have seasonality and others that don't. The final model that ETS produces already accounts for your seasonality, so you don't need to account for it.

If you want to isolate and visualize the seasonal components in your data, then you should try decompose() or stl(). They will display the seasonal component of your data.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but to clarify - does the first value (267.84) correspond with the first value in my time series (quarter 1)?  Or does it correspond with quarter 4?  I just don't understand what seasonal component is being used for what quarter.

Comment: `plot(fit)` will show you the seasonal component and help you identify what corresponds to what time period. The initial seasonal states are for the period *before* the data starts.